# Promotion on semistandard Young tableaux.

Tags: combinatorics, young-tableaux

I searched on google and found that algorithms describe promotion operator on the set of standard Young tableaux. For example, [the article](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Epeal/polynomials/tableauOperators.htm). But I didn't find algorithms describe promotion operator on the set of semistandard Young tableaux. Are there some reference which describe algorithms of promotion operator on the set of semistandard Young tableaux? Thank you very much.

Comment: Not that I really know anything about this, but on the very page you linked to, just below the entry on promotion, there's “$k$-promotion”, which acts on SSYT with entries $\le k$.

Answer (score 0):

One algorithm is described in Appendix A of [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.09337.pdf).